# Why is this animate marginTop function is not working like I expect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Still trying to figure this out from yesterday.

I am trying to scroll an element up 50 pixels at a time by animating it's "marginTop" property.  Problem is, on each click of my trigger, the element "resets" and animates from 0.  Can anyone explain this confusing behaviour to me?

Look at my alerts here

```
$(document).on("click",".scroll-control",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newMarginTop = parseInt($('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop'));
    alert (newMarginTop);  // returns 0
    newMarginTop = newMarginTop - 50;
    alert (newMarginTop);  // returns -50
    $('.scroll-frame').animate({"margin-top": newMarginTop},1000);
    var newMarginTop = parseInt($('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop'));
    alert (newMarginTop);  // returns 0  <<< ??? Why not -50 ???    
});
```

Comment: This is working http://jsfiddle.net/7zYBR/4/, working.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/7zYBR/9/, it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe think about using a relative position instead of negative margins. Using a negative margin can go wrong, especially in older browsers.

```
/* CSS */
.scroll-control{
position:relative;
}
```

Then use:

```
/* Javascript */
$(".scroll-control").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var newTop = $('.scroll-frame').css('top');
    newTop = newTop - 50;
    $('.scroll-frame').animate({"top": newTop},1000);  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `animate` method is asynchronous. The animation doesn't actually start until after you exit from your function. The code right after the `animate` call runs immediately, not after the animation is complete.

If you want to do something after the animation, you need to use a callback:

```
$('.scroll-frame').animate({"margin-top": newMarginTop}, 1000, function(){
  var newMarginTop = parseInt($('.scroll-frame').css('marginTop'));
  alert (newMarginTop);
});
```

Comment: Ok.. thats good to know, but my alert after the animation was just for troubleshooting.  The fact remains that each time I run the function, the element animates from marginTop 0 to -50.  Even with your info, the *second* time I run the function I should get -50 when I check marginTop, and it should animate from -50 to -100, correct?  But each time I run the function my first alert returns 0, even after an animation has been run.  Ideas?